# How are downloads scheduled from hughes net with ubuntu

Tags: downloads

I want to download files during Hughes Net bounus hours.
Searched several different ways on the internet with no luck.
Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: You have not described your current method of downloading. Web browser? ftp? wget? torrent? something else?

Comment: I use Firefox. Do not know anything about the other methods.